# How would a species without optical vision navigate a spaceship?

Tags: spaceships, anatomy

I wanted to create an alien species with an interstellar civilization, but the twist is that they never developed eyes, due to evolving on a planet far enough away from its star that it’s shrouded in perpetual darkness. To compensate, they have an enhanced sense of hearing far superior to that of humans.

My question though is how they could navigate a spaceship without being able to see. My initial idea was that they possess windowless submarine-like ships that navigate their surroundings through the use of extremely powerful sonar, but I’m not sure if that is feasible.

Comment: What do you mean by "navigate a spaceship"? If you mean how they move inside from place to place, well, they do it the same way they move within their appartements dirt-side. If you mean how to they steer the ship, then I don't understand the point of the question. Spacecraft are not steered by looking out a window, not even at close quarters. Watch a video of how SpaceX's Dragon capsules approach and dock with the International Space Station, and note that nobody is looking outside, and everybody is looking at instruments.

Comment: the interesting question is whether they would ever even build space ships. the stars would only be interesting data on obscure instruments from scientists to them.

Comment: Frame challenge: how do your species get energy gradient on which to live, without extraplanetary light? Living on warm ground with cold air is possible if the planet is hot on the inside, yet most likely it'll get cold faster than life would develop high enough to even consider lifting off (where by the way?) And should they have at least some infrared vision, it's quite a substitution to optical vision.

Comment: Far enough from a star to be shrouded in complete darkness usually buys "cold enough that there's no gaseous atmosphere for sonar to function."   And on the vision scale, "as dark as a moonless night" is still bright enough to make earthly eyes useful, though not guaranteed to develop. Even out in the Oort,  the non-sun Stars aren't significantly different in their brightness than they are at Earth.

Comment: **We MUST clear up some confusion** Please [edit] your post and clearly state whether you species is trying to (a) navigate the space ship through space or (b) navigate the corridors of the space ship. (Note that I'm pretty sure a question has been previously asked about how a blind civilization would discover radio, visible light, etc., but can't find it right now - that's your biggest problem. You could use radar, if a blind civilization could ever discover it.)

Comment: Have you read "Project Hail Mary" by Andy Weir? It has exactly what you're talking about.

Answer (score 2):

"Extremely powerful sonar" is indeed not feasible, as sonar doesn't work in vacuum.

Radar, on the other hand, works fine, as does lidar, and passive optical observation.

In other words, they will navigate their ships exactly the same way we do, with instruments that augment their natural senses. The only difference is in the display hardware that translates instrument readings into something they can understand.

Comment: There was a question on the site that once asked something like how a blind civilization would discover light? I can't find it. Do you remember it? My knee-jerk reaction is that a blind civilization would be hard pressed to discover radar, radio, or anything having to do with optics.

Comment: @JBH had the same question myself. My answer to myself was that heat/IR radiation was the gateway to discovery of the rest of the EM spectrum.

Comment: @jbh I assume you'd get there through electricity, with optics being derived from Alien Maxwell's equations and tested in the lab, rather than constructed from observations. Optics as part of modern physics, rather than classical physics, in other words.

Comment: Not saying it can't be done, folks. Just saying that old question would be very pertinent to this one.

Comment: The largest obstacle IMHO would be the need, in the beginning of discovery, in order to gather information about a subject, they would in many cases need to touch a thing in order to progress their knowledge of it. Obviously, touching many things in a scientific experimental setting would be detrimental.  While in some cases there would be ways around this. Situations where methods of observing where imaging though sound is  imposable would severally hinder scientific progression.

Answer (score 1):

If they use echolocation, they can use [3D audio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_audio_effect): headphones + advanced algorithms that generate the sound that mimics what echolocation would sound in a computer-generated virtual space much like we use visual displays that mimic what *we* would *see* in a computer-generated virtual space.

Comment: In essence, projecting an auditory "Hologram" instead of a visual one, I like it.

Answer (score 1):

### Just because they can't see does not prevent them from using EM sensors

Humans currently chart out space using the whole EM spectrum.  We can't see radio waves, xrays etc. but we've still designed tools to detect these things.  In all likelihood, your aliens were totally oblivious to the existence of stars and planets for most of thier planet's history until they hit 20th century technology and started experimenting with radio communications and radar at which point they would start detecting strange background noise from the great void above.

Curiosity will lead them to experiment until they map out the source of this radio noise, and over time they will use thier expanding understanding of the invisible EM spectrum to not only develop telescope technology, but to map out the cosmos in its full EM spectrum just as we have done.

The only difference is that they will need to translate these images into some manner of brail or sound encoding to view thier representation of the universe the same way that we have to translate things like IR images into the visible light spectrum.

Answer (score 0):

A sort of nano-tic machinery, that turns solar systems, planets etc into solid, touchable objects, with a scale addition. Electrically charge these "braille" guis and you can feel them even from a distance with a sense for electrical fields. But at this technological level, why not implants? Light is the default medium too look upon the universe. And to have translation devices, before inventing space travel seems.. natural.